# Accessing Parent Data in a Meteor Template Helper

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a template for a collection of Groups. Each group document contains an array with each element containing a number and a boolean. The template is laid out as follows:

```
<template name="group">
  <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}} groupBox">

    <button class="delete">&times;</button>

    <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked-group" />

    <span class="text">{{name}}</span>

    <ul>
      {{#each this.numbers}}
        <li class="checked">
          <button class="deleteNumber">&times;</button>

          <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked-number" />

          <span class="text">{{number}}</span>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>

    <form class="new-number">
      <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Type to add a number to this group" />
    </form>

  </li>
</template>
```

An example group document is laid out as such:

```
{
  "_id": "pSpNcJKDPhRtGhtov",
  "name": "Sample Group",
  "createdAt": "2015-06-27T00:45:39.137Z",
  "owner": "t2ELweZsZqJXNQqdZ",
  "username": "brodan",
  "checked": false,
  "numbers": [
    {
      "number": "1234567",
      "checked": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to be able to remove a specific number from the numbers array when I click on the deleteNumber button. I have the following javascript and can't figure out how to get the parent context to use in the MongoDB query:

```
Template.group.events({
    "click .deleteNumber": function () {
      Meteor.call("deleteNumber");
    }
  });

Meteor.methods({
  deleteNumber: function (numbers) {
    //Need to delete number from group via MongoDB query here.
  }
});
```

I know that I can use the $pull operator in my MongoDB query in the deleteNumber method, but in order to get the right group, I need to have the parent data from the number in the template.

**Solved thanks to xamfoo's answer.**

The working deleteNumber method is now set up like this:

```
deleteNumber: function (groupId, number) {
    Groups.update(groupId, {$pull: {numbers: {"number": number}}});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get the context via `this` in the event handler and group data with `Template.instance().data`:

```
Template.group.events({
    "click .deleteNumber": function () {
      var data = Template.instance().data;
      Meteor.call("deleteNumber", data._id, this.number);
    }
  });
```

In this case, parameters of `deleteNumber` are:

```
Meteor.methods({
  deleteNumber: function (groupId, number) {
    //Need to delete number from group via MongoDB query here.
  }
});
```

You can also access the data context with `Template.currentData()` or `Template.parentData()`.

Comment: This worked flawlessly. Thank you very much for the help. I knew that there was some way to get context within the template handler and not just in the template but I couldn't figure it out.